# Blazor - how to install nuget packages into project folder

Tags: nuget, blazor

I have a simple Blazor application - I need to install jQuery, however, when I use the NuGet package manager to do so in Visual Studio 2019 it is installing a reference to the package where the package is placed in c:\users....

I have Visual Studio options for NuGet set to packages.config in package management and I was expecting to get a packages file in the Blazor code directory.

I need the jQuery to be accessible site relative (so under wwwroot\js or something like that).

Does anyone know how to get VS/Blazor to do this?

Comment: Nuget is for installing server side things. To install client side libs, use Libman: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/client-side-package-management-with-library-manager-in-visual-studio-2017libman/

Comment: Howerver, as JQuery is not under active development anymore, I would simply add the link in the _host page as a CDN.

Comment: @Guilherme Nope. You can absolutely use Nuget in your client project. That's the beauty about blazor.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use CDN? Just add this line to your `index.html` (in client project)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or you can choose from [here](https://code.jquery.com/)

Or you can download the file and place it somewhere inside your wwwroot folder.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652453/jquery-not-working-properly-with-my-blazor-app) may be helpful.

Comment: The app does not have internet access so cannot use external references.  I need to be able to reference code locally.   Hence I need NuGet to install the package(s) into the application folder somewhere.  jQuery was just an example package :)