# Blazor webassembly component refreshes data only on initial page load

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created blazor library that uses google maps and google places autocomplete for my project. I tied to implement autocomplete with map navigation to selected place. Now I am testing it with blazor webassembly and I am currently stuck with strange behaviour.

1. Component updates data only when page is first time loaded.
2. When page is navigated again, component doesn't respond to data change, even the change is triggered correctly.

Basically javascript function triggers method PlacesChanged

```
internal class GooglePlaceEventInfo
{
    private string _textBoxElementId;
    private Func<string, Task> _autocompleteInitializedCallback;
    private Func<GooglePlace, string, Task> _placeChangedCallback;

    public GooglePlaceEventInfo(string textBoxElementId, 
        Func<string, Task> autocompleteInitializedCallback, 
        Func<GooglePlace, string, Task> placeChangedCallback)
    {
        _textBoxElementId = textBoxElementId;
        _autocompleteInitializedCallback = autocompleteInitializedCallback;
        _placeChangedCallback = placeChangedCallback;
    }

    //Map evetns
    [JSInvokable("PlacesInitialized")]
    public async Task PlacesInitialized(string textBoxElementId)
    {
        if (_textBoxElementId != textBoxElementId)
        {
            throw new InvalidProgramException($"{nameof(PlacesInitialized)} method was called with invalid id container Div Id: {textBoxElementId}, expected Id is {_textBoxElementId}.");
        }

        if (_autocompleteInitializedCallback is not null)
        {
            await _autocompleteInitializedCallback.Invoke(textBoxElementId);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable("PlacesChanged")]
    public async Task PlacesChanged(GooglePlace places, string textBoxElementId)
    {
        if (_textBoxElementId != textBoxElementId)
        {
            throw new InvalidProgramException($"{nameof(PlacesInitialized)} method was called with invalid id container Div Id: {textBoxElementId}, expected Id is {_textBoxElementId}.");
        }

        if (_placeChangedCallback is not null)
        {
            await _placeChangedCallback.Invoke(places, textBoxElementId);
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is a method in page where component is located. Two fields: _mapCenter, _zoomLevel are holding data that is used to trigger change in component.

```
private Task PlaceChanged(GooglePlace place, string textBoxElementId)
{
    if (place != null)
    {
        PlaceMarkerOnMap(place);
        var position = new GeolocationData(place.Geometry.Location.Lat, place.Geometry.Location.Lng);
        _mapCenter = position;
        _zoomLevel = 14;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Component:

```
                   <GoogleMap @ref="_googleMap"
                   Center="@_mapCenter"
                   Zoom="@_zoomLevel"
                   UsePlacesLibrary="true"
                   ApiKey="@_googleMapsApiKey" />
```

Everything is working fine on first page load. Means that map is set to desired position and the marker is placed. But navigation to different page and renavigation to map page breaks whole thing. PlacesChanged is still triggered but map component doesn't update itself. It just looks like StateHasChanged() does not have any effect anymore. Any help or thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit: I wrote this part of my code wrongly. I was trying to attach proces to existing component, but instead I had to move the logic to separate component. After this everything is working perfectly. Thank you [enet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152891/enet) for pointing me in right direction. I also published this library [on github](https://github.com/Adlorem/Blazor.Component.Maps) if anybody is interested in such functionality.**

Comment: Can you show us how `_mapCenter` and `_zoomLevel` are used in your component?

Comment: Your English is not native, and you provide partial info of the objects involved. So it is really hard to understand the issue. However, I'd suggest you check the following: I guess that `_placeChangedCallback` is an event handler which you try to invoke asyncronously, but uses a syncronous method (Invoke) instead. This may result in Blazor skip calling the StateHasChanged method, thus preventing the refreshment of the component. Try to use InvokeAsync instead.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I also think this is synchronization problem. I have updated my code.

Comment: This answer with working code should help you. Try to adapt your code to mine, as in principal what you're trying to do is similar to what I do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64572906/6152891

Comment: Thank you for letting me understand the error of my way. I was doing it wrong. After some code rewrite everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to overcome this same kind of issue with a leaflet map being called via JSInterop. What I ended up doing was making the map div itself a component, with a bool parameter of "display: @isVisible ? block : none"

I put that component into my actual MainLayout.razor, which was my central layout for the multiple tabs I had.

Then I used a LocationChangingHandler via injected NavigationManager to detect when the user navigated to the "Map" page, setting that parameter true.